# Label stops updating after navigating to another activity and back

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm developing a test app with Xamarin and I got a UI problem.

The app consists of two activities - let's call them First and Second.

In the First activity there is an event handler which, once called, updates a label:

```
        Action action = delegate
        {
            _labelPlaybackStatus.Text = status;
        };

        RunOnUiThread(action);
```

When the app is started, the First activity (being the entry point of the app) is launched and the label updates just fine. The app is running on a test device and I can see the label updating.

But if I navigate from First to Second and then return back to First - the label stops updating visually. If I set a breakpoint I see that the event handler is triggered and the line `RunOnUiThread(action)` is executed, but visually on the test device nothing happens - the label text remains the same.

The navigation between both activities is executed with `StartActivity(intent)`. The line `_labelPlaybackStatus = FindViewById(Resource.Id.labelPlaybackStatus);` is executed in OnCreate of the First activity, so the field is re-initialized upon return to First.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I'm having it now but not always. Sometimes a label freezes and only starts working again if I close/reopen the app. But sometimes it just works. I don't know how to make it happen or why.

Answer (score 0):

The OnCreated is only called when the activity is created.
I'm not sure but I think you have a problem with your **_labelPlaybackStatus** variable because you populated it in **OnCreated**

You can put your code under **OnCreated** in **OnResume**, it can resolve your problem.